# Shopify App requesting permission to new scope

Tags: shopify

One of my shopify apps will require a new scope (read_orders). What is the best way to ask our existing users for permissions to this new scope?

Does the user need to re-install the app?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you do. This is because the access token you receive after you specify your scope is only limited to your older permissions.

Answer (score 2):

you just have to redirect merchant for Oauth process with new scope Shopify will automatically redirect merchant for updating APP. after the merchant update the app
he will be redirected to your callback function. now your app has new permission and you need not to delete accessToken